how to receive RTP packet using socket in python
I'm writing a program in Python that receives frame information via RTSP address and outputs it via imshow() function.
I know that this code can be easily implemented by utilizing cv2.videocapture().
However, I have a big problem: the RTSP camera I'm using requires Digest authentication instead of Basic authentication to receive RTSP video.
So I sent a describe, setup, and play request over a socket connection and got an RTP-Info response.
However, when I connected to the RTP server, there are no packets coming through (I even checked with wire shark).
What should I check and code?
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", 1212))  #when request <SETUP>, client_port 1212-1213

print("RTP stream receive...")

while True:
    packet, _ = sock.recvfrom(65536)
    rtp_payload = parse_rtp_packet(packet)
    
    
    frame = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(rtp_payload, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    if frame is None:
        continue


    cv2.imshow('RTSP Frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


sock.close()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Right now, the RTSP camera and the client are on different networks.
Of course, the RTSP is port-forwarded, so the CLIENT can access it, but the RTP server is not port-forwarded.
Is that why I can't get it?

Does it work with common tools, like GStreamer? gst-launch-1.0 -v uridecodebin uri='rtsp://host:port/test.sdp' ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw ! autovideosink

Did you Setup rtp/tcp eg. Interleaved or rtp/udp?

@bartolo-otrit We have verified that the video is output via gstreamer, but gstreamer is not suitable for our system implementation, so we are using this method.

@Christoph setup request to complete the setup. I used Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=xxxx-xxxx.

did you check with wireshark could it be that its interleaved and send on the rtsp port like 554

Does your implementation work with this test RTSP stream from a file? vlc video.mp4 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=5000,sdp=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8081/test.sdp}'

@Christoph I checked, but I only see packets related to RTSP authentication and no packets for RTSP video.

@bartolo-otrit  Do you mean this code or do I need to change some of it?

The code you run on your machine. The published code doesn't provide any useful information because parse_rtp_packet is not defined.
